# find string containing least operations to make all characters same

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 3 string(for ex- aabacc,bababb,aaaaba) of equal no. of characters. I want to compare them and find the string which takes less operation to become all character same. Let's say string(aabacc) take 3 operation to become(aaaaaa) while string (bababb) take 2 operation to become(bbbbbb) and string(aaaaba) take 1 operation to become same(aaaaaa). So the output will be string(aaaaba) and operation 1. Can anybody tell me how to approach this problem. I doesn't need entire code even small logic is helpful.

```
 # Function to find the minimum
# operations to convert given
# string to another with equal
# frequencies of characters
def minOperations(s,p,r):

# Frequency of characters
freq = [0] * 26
freq1 = [0] * 26
freq2 = [0] * 26
n = len(s)
n1 = len(p)
n2 = len(q)


# Loop to find the Frequency
# of each character
for i in range(n):
    freq[ord(s[i]) - ord('A')] += 1
    for i1 in range(n1):
         freq[ord(p[i1] - ord('A')] += 1
         for i2 in range(n2):
             freq[ord(r[i2] - ord('A')] += 1


# Sort in decreasing order
# based on frequency
freq.sort(reverse = True)
    freq1.sort(reverse = True)
         freq2.sort(reverse = True)

# Maximum possible answer
answer = n
answer1 = n1
answer2 = n2

# Loop to find the minimum operations
# required such that frequency of
# every character is equal
for i in range(1, 27):
    if (n % i == 0):
        x = n //i
        y = 0

        for j in range(i):
            y += min(freq[j], x)

        answer = min(answer, n - y)

    for i1 in range(1,27):
        if(n1 % i1 == 0):
             x1 = n1 // i1
             y1 = 0

             for j1 in range(i1):
                 y1 += min(freq1[j1], x1)
             answer1 = min(answer1, n1 - y1)

         for i2 in range(1,27):
            if(n2 % i2 == 0):
                 x2 = n2 // i2
                 y2 = 0 

                 for j2 in range(i2):
                     y2 += min(freq2[j2], x2)
                 answer2 = min(answer2, n2 - y2)            

if (answer < answer1)&&(answer  < answer2):
     print(answer)
elif (answer1 < answer) && (answer < answer3):
     print(answer1)
else:
     print(answer2) 



# Driver Code
if __name__ == "__main__":

s = "BBC"
p = "AAD"
R = "DDD"

print (minOperations(s,p,r))
```

Comment: Writing a single source file with both python and C is very hard work. I suggest you stick to one language at a time.

Comment: Putting C code in perl or tcl scripts is easy, though, if you can use something besides python.

Comment: @pmg Are you just mocking OP for including the `c` tag, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
word = 'aaaaba'
counts = Counter(word)
max_freq = max(counts.values())
conversions = len(word) - max_freq
```

To get the minimum operations to make all characters of a string same, convert all characters

- Get the frequency of all characters in the string.
- Get the character with maximum frequency (say, `max_freq`)
- Now convert all other characters, except the one with maximum frequency, to that character with max freq. The number of conversions required is `string_length - max_freq`.

Comment: You might also use `max_freq = counts.most_common(1)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the formulation of the problem, the solution could look like this:

```
def str_cmp(str1):
    charset = set(str1)
    frequent = max(str1.count(s) for s in charset)
    return str1, len(str1) - frequent


print(str_cmp('aabacc'))
print(str_cmp('bababb'))
print(str_cmp('aaaaba'))
```

**Output**

```
('aabacc', 3)
('bababb', 2)
('aaaaba', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the string that takes the least amount of operations (substitute char for char) to equalize with respect to individual characters, isn't the answer always just the result of finding the string for which the amount of characters different from the most frequent character is minimized?

```
def evaluate(string):
    assert len(string) > 0
    freq = {string[0]: 1}
    most_frequent = string[0]
    for char in string[1:]:
        if char in freq:
            freq[char] += 1
            if char != most_frequent and freq[most_frequent] < freq[char]:
                most_frequent = char
        else:
            freq[char] = 1

    return len(string) - freq[most_frequent]

def solve(A):
    best = min(A, key=evaluate)
    print(best)

solve(["awd", "awdawdawd", "awodijawd"])
```

Comment: Size is same for all three strings

Comment: @AryanTyagi Well this solution is more general. It definitely handles the case where all strings are the same length.

Comment: @AryanTyagi So, have you checked out my solution? Does it work for you?